# Trouble with getting Canvas Data after Drawing image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This code works well as it shoulds:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.id = "myCanvas";
    canvas.style.height = "640px";
    canvas.style.width = "384px";
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
    var imgd = context.getImageData(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 1, 1);
    var pix = imgd.data;

    document.getElementById("listener").innerHTML = "<b><i>" + message + "<br>" + pix[3] + "</i></b>";
  }, false);
</script>

<div id="listener" >
</div>
```

It basically writes the mouse Position to the "listener" div and the alpha of the current pixel (as long as there is no content, it's - of course - 0)

But when i add this code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.animefighters.de/images/armor_leatherbelly.png';
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

There wouldn't happen anything...
What am i doing wrong? Where is the mistake?
I want to draw some images to the canvas and, after that, get the pixel data (including mouse Position and alpha of the pixel) ... 
how can i realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to draw the image on the canvas before it is loaded, you need to draw it onload:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src = 'http://www.animefighters.de/images/armor_leatherbelly.png';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, at least the image is loaded... But now, another problem came up: When I hover the canvas object, there neither is said anything about the position of the mouse nor anything about the alpha-value... do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I need to see the code to understand the issue better. In any case, if this problem is solved you should accept it, and post another question for your other issue. (You can then post a link to your new question here in the comment)